# How to specify child component template class based on parent component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my child object I have a div that I want to set the class to be "class1" when the parent component is Parent1, and I want to set that same div's class to be "class2" when parent component is Parent2.

Parent1 component template:

```
<div>...</div>
<childcomponent><childcomponent>
```

Parent2 component template:

```
<div>...</div>
<childcomponent><childcomponent>
```

Child component template when in Parent1:

```
<div class="class1">...</div>
```

Child component template when in Parent2:

```
<div class="class2">...</div>
```

Is this possible? If so, what code do I need?